# Problems of clipping in 4D homogeneous space?

Tags: clipping, rasterizing, homogenous-transformation

I am learning programmable rendering pipeline by implementing a tiny software renderer. I try to implement it in a 'hardware' style. However, I am not familiar with the GPU pipeline and got some problems of homogeneous clipping.

According to [this thread](https://www.opengl.org/discussion_boards/showthread.php/171975-Homogenous-Normalized-Device-Coords-and-clipping?p=1211054&viewfull=1#post1211054), suppose we have two points `e0`, `e1` in 3D eye coordinate, which are projected to `h0(-70, -70, 118, 120)`, `h1(-32, -99, -13, -11)` in the 4D homogeneous clipping space. Then we do interpolation in 4D homogeneous space, the segment `h0-h1` is clipped by plane `w = -x` (`z = -1` in NDC) at 4D point `h(t)=t*h1+(1-t)*h2`, with `t = 0.99`. Without loss of generality, suppose we have `h0-h(0.99)` part (which is viewable) feeding to the rasterization stage. So we need to generate the corresponding vertex properties of `h(0.99)` (same as the output format of vertex shader). My question is how to generate these new vertices' properties?

**Update**: I try to use t as the interpolate variable to get the vertex properties of h(t), and get reasonable result. I am wondering why the `t` from 4D space can get good interpolation result in 3D vertex properties?

Comment: "*I am learning programmable rendering pipeline by implementing a tiny software renderer.*" That's not really an effective way of learning that.

Comment: @NicolBolas Haha exactly, but I have been walking along this way for two weeks (repository https://github.com/stanleytangerror/TinyRenderer), met several problems. By the way, what would you recommend for me, to unlock skill tree of 3D programming, I have a few coding experiences of OpenGL 3.3?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I am wondering why the t from 4D space can get good interpolation result in 3D vertex properties?

Because that's how math works. Or more to the point, that's how *linear* math works.

Without getting too deep into the mathematics, a [linear transformation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_map) is a transformation between two spaces that preserves the linear nature of the original space. For example, two lines that are parallel to one another will remain parallel after a linear transformation. If you perform a 2x scale in the Y direction, the new lines will be longer and farther from the origin. But they will still be parallel.

Let's say we have a line AB, and you define the point C which is the midpoint between A and B. If you perform the same linear transformation on A, B, and C, the new point C<sub>1</sub> will *still* be on the line A<sub>1</sub>B<sub>1</sub>. Not only that, C<sub>1</sub> will still be the *midpoint* of the new line.

We can even generalize this. C could be *any point* which fits the following equation: `C = (B-A)t + A`, for any `t`. A linear transformation of A, B and C will not affect change ***`t`*** in this equation.

In fact, that is what a linear transformation really means: it's a transformation that preserves `t` in that equation, for all points A, B, and C in the original space.

The fact that you have 4 dimensions in your space is ultimately irrelevant to the vector equation above. Linear transformations in any space will preserve `t`. A matrix transform represents a linear transformation from one space to another (usually).

Also, your original 3D positions were really 4D positions, with the W assumed to be 1.0.

Do be aware however that the transformation from clip-space (4D homogeneous) to [normalized-device-coordinate space](https://www.opengl.org/wiki/Vertex_Post-Processing#Perspective_divide) (3D non-homogeneous) is *non-linear*. The division-by-W is not a linear transformation. That's one reason why you do clipping in 4D homogeneous clip-space, where we still preserve a linear relationship between the original positions and clip-space.

This is also why [perspective-correct interpolation of per-vertex outputs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Texture_mapping#Perspective_correctness) is important: because the space you're doing your rasterization in (window space) is *not* a linear transformation of the original space output by the vertex shader (clip space). This means that `t` is not properly preserved. When interpolating, you usually need to compensate for that in order to maintain the linear relationships of your per-vertex values.

Comment: That's the point, thanks a lot. I used to treat those space as a 3D space with an extra scaling factor w, except for 4D homogeneous space. Now I can see how it works. You do help me a lot.